# How to Change label value on drp selected change event in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have below code and I want to change label text base on selected role.

For example, If I select Admin then in label Text I need "Admin Name" etc.

I use below code but I is not working.

```
 <div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RoleID, new SelectList(ViewBag.RoleLsit, "Id", "RoleName"), "Select Category", new { onchange = "SelectedIndexChanged()" })
</div>

<div>        
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RoleName)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RoleName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoleName)
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

function SelectedIndexChanged() {

    var sub = document.getElementsByName("RoleName");
    sub.value = "Selected Role Name";

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Unclear what your trying to do. Why in the world do you have a input for `RoleName` when you already have a dropdownlist for the `RoleID`?

Comment: I just want to change label text based on Drp selected event. In Above code is just a demo for this question.

Comment: Which _label text_? (do you mean the label generated by `@Html.LabelFor(model => model.RoleName)`?)

Comment: yes. I am new in mvc. is there any other way to change label text ? Thanks for your reply

Comment: Doing so simply makes so sense at all and its hard to understand what your trying to achieve. But (using jquery)  `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.RoleName, new { id = "rolenamelabel" })` and `$('#RoleID').change(function() { $('#rolenamelabel').text($(this).children('option:selected').text()); })`

Comment: sry sir, but its not working

Comment: Yes it does - and [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f679d5zt/) proves it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could find your elements using `@Html.IdFor`, if your js is in your view.

```
function SelectedIndexChanged() {
    //find the label
    var label = document.querySelector('label[for="@Html.IdFor(m => m.RoleName)"]');

    //get the dropDown selected option text
    var dropDown = document.getElementById("@Html.IdFor(m => m.RoleId)");
    var selectedText = dropDown.options[dropDown.selectedIndex].text;

    //set the label text
    label.innerHTML=selectedText

}
```

By the way, taking a look a jQuery might be an "interesting" option.
You could simply remove the `new { onchange = "SelectedIndexChanged()"` , then

```
$('#@Html.IdFor(m => m.RoleId)').change(function() {
    $('label[for="@Html.IdFor(m => m.RoleName)"]').text($(this).children('option:selected').text());

});
```

Answer (score 0):

function SelectedIndexChanged() {

```
document.getElementsById("RoleName").InnerHtml="Role name goes here";
```

}
you should use get element by id instead of name because when this html helper renders the strongly typed binded attributes becomes the id of that control . so in your case role name will be the ID

Comment: Label has no `id` when generated by `@Html.LabelFor`, it has a `for` attribute